# Access Event Of Component That Is Passed As Prop

Tags: semantic-ui, react-props, composition, react-component, react-class-based-component

I pass a [React Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) as a [Prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#props) to a child.
That component has an [event](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).
In child component, I want to get access to that event and bind it to a method inside child. How can I do that ?

I often use [Semantic-UI](https://semantic-ui.com/) [React Modal](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) as following:

```js
class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            modalOpen: false
        }
    }    

    handleOpen = () => this.setState({ modalOpen: true })

    handleClose = () => this.setState({ modalOpen: false })

    render(){
        return(
            <Modal 
                onClose={this.handleClose}
                open={this.state.modalOpen}
                trigger={<Button onClick={this.handleOpen}>Gandalf</Button>}>
                <Modal.Header>Balrog</Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Content>
                    <h1>You shall not pass!</h1>
                    {/* 
                    Some form that closes Modal on success
                    onSuccess : this.handleClose 
                    */}
                    <Button onClick={this.handleClose}>Grrrrr</Button>
                </Modal.Content>
            </Modal>
        )
    }
}

export default Example
```

Now I want to make it reusable

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class ReusableModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            modalOpen: false
        }
    }    

    handleOpen = () => this.setState({ modalOpen: true })

    handleClose = () => this.setState({ modalOpen: false })

    render(){
        return(
            <Modal 
                onClose={() => this.handleClose}
                open={this.state.modalOpen}
                {/* 
                    How to access onClick event on trigger prop content ?  
                    this.prop.trigger can be a Button or a Menu.Item
                */}
                {...this.props}>
                {this.props.children}
            </Modal>
        )
    }
}
```

How can I have access to the trigger prop Component and bind its onClick event to handleOpen method ?

**Edit :**

to be more precise here is what I'm looking for

```
<ChildComponent trigger={<Button>This button should fire a function defined in child component</Button>} />


ChildComponent extends Component {
    functionToCall = () => { console.log('hello') }
    // I would like to :
    // let myButton = this.props.trigger
    // myButton.onClick = functionToCall
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is to clone element

```
ChildComponent extends Component {
    functionToCall = () => { console.log('hello') }

    this.Trigger = React.cloneElement(
        this.props.trigger,
        { onClick: this.functionToCall }
    )   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In React, data flows from parent to child. If there are multiple child components that have events that need to trigger changes in parent component you must fire callback function in child component.

Parent component:

```
handleOpen = () => { // do something }
(...)
<childComponent onClickCallback={this.handleOpen}
```

And in child component:

```
<button onClick={this.props.onClickCallback}> Click to close</button>
```

Pass `this.handleOpen` as a prop and call it as a prop in child component, and it will trigger function in the parent component, where you can handle data however you want.

Is this what you asked for?